# Is there a way to get pageCount from Itunes Search API? When retrieving an ebook?

Tags: api, itunes-search-api

I developing an app where you can search for books. In the response from Itunes Search API i can retrieve the title, author, book cover as need but i can't see the page count of each book anywhere in the response?

Is it not possible to get from the Itunes Search API?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not returned in the JSON (and it isn't) of your lookup unfortunately you can't.